# Загрузка файла на сервер JS

Tags: javascript, html

есть html файл в нем input:

```
<input type="file" id="file1" />
```

Как чисто по средствам JS загрузить его на сервер в уже имеющуюся папку,без PHP и каких либо фреймворков.

Comment: может быть node js или смесь js + php

Comment: А возможно это сделать без фреймворков и php?

Comment: node.js - это не фреймворк - это серверный вариант javascript

Comment: Окей, понял. А чисто через обычный JS это возможно сделать?

Comment: наверно  нет - так как javascript работает только в той вкладке в которой открыт

Comment: так как я не совсем компетентный то давайте подождём кого то кто на много лучше меня знает javascript

Comment: вам все равно надо будет на сервере этот файл принять и положить куда вы хотите. браузер может только отправить файл по определенному маршруту (урлу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак, код выполняется в браузере и не может никак взаимодействовать с файловой системой сервера.

Вам нужно реализовать логику сохранения файла на любом языке программирования, который может исполняться на сервере.